# How to keep the single resource representation approach using OpenAPI spec

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

Reading this [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20161214184632/http://apihandyman.io/writing-openapi-swagger-specification-tutorial-part-5-advanced-input-and-output-modeling/) (see: *3 How to use a single definition when...*) about describing a REST API using OpenAPI (Swagger) specification you can note how to keep a single resource representation for adding/updating and getting resource using *readOnly* property instead of having one representation for getting (GET a collection item) and other one for adding (POST to a collection). For example, in the following User single representation, the **id** is a read-only property which mean that it won't be sent in the representation when a user is created, it will be there when a user is retrieved.

```
"User":
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64",
            "readOnly": true
        },
        "company_data": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                .
                .
                .
            },
            "readOnly": false
        }
    }
}
```

It is really clean and nice to keep the list of resource representation as short as possible so I want to keep the single resource representation approach but the problem I am facing to do that is: how to manage *required* when a property is mandatory for input only? Suppose I need to set *company_data* as required when the user is created (POST /users/) but non-required when an user is retrieved (GET /users/{user_id}). There are any way in OpenAPI specification to satisfy this need without lost the single resource representation?

Comment: My answer below. You might also want to look at RAPID-ML, which we designed to make canonical data models highly adaptable, thus easier to reuse and standardize across APIs: http://rapid-api.org/rapid-ml

Answer (score 2):

From the Swagger-OpenAPI [2.0 spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#user-content-fixed-fields-13), `readonly` is defined as follows:

> Declares the property as "read only". This means that it MAY be sent
>   as part of a response but MUST NOT be sent as part of the request.
>   Properties marked as readOnly being true SHOULD NOT be in the required
>   list of the defined schema. Default value is false.

Since the specification says that a read-only property should not be required, there are no defined semantics for what `readonly` + `required` should mean.

(It might have been reasonable to say that `readonly` + `required` means it's required in the response, but still excluded from the request. In fact there is an [open issue](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/228) to make this change, and it looks like it's under consideration for [OpenAPI 3.0](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/tree/OpenAPI.next).)

Unfortunately there is no way for a single schema to make properties required in the request, but optional (or disallowed) in the response.

(Again, there's an [open issue](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/425) proposing a "write-only" modifier, possibly under consideration for the next release.)

For now, you would need to create different schemas for these different cases. As [described here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/425#issuecomment-212106574), you might be able to make these schemas a bit more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) using `allOf` composition.